# Почему происходит ошибка, "связанная с сетью или определённым экземпляром"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Постоянно получаю данную ошибку при попытке создать подключение в Visual Studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подробно описать, как вы пытались создать подключение к базе?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Могу ли отправить на почту мой файл doc . Я сделал скрины каждого шага.

Comment: 1. Добавить новый источник данных  2. Выбор типа источника данных (База данных)  3. Выбор модели базы данных (Набор данных)  4. Выбор подключения к базу данных (Создать подключение)  5. Выбор источника данных (Файл базы данных Microsoft SQL Server) 6. Добавить подключение (создаю файл базы данных например testDB)

Comment: Далее нажимаю ОК, достаточно долго пытается выполнить и выдает вышеуказанную ошибку.